# Conditional Probability after introducing new event

Tags: probability

You've got a test for cancer. For a population of 1000 people, 40 will have cancer. The test identified cancer in 30 of these people, and then in 65 of the people without cancer. From this, we know that P(C) = 0.04, P(T|C) = 0.75, and P(T|~C) = 0.067...., where C means cancer and T means a positive test. So, if we had a group of 100 people who tested positive, around 32 would have cancer, because P(C|T) = P(C and T)/P(T) = $\frac{(30/1000)}{(95/1000)} = 31.57...$. I think that I grasp this concept of conditional probability fairly well.

But what if someone tests positive for cancer, and then the doctor determines that they are of a population in which 40% of the people have this cancer? How would you calculate the probability that they actually have cancer?

My work: I recognize that this is asking P(C and T and P). Using the laws of conditional probability, I note that P(a and b and c) can be written as P(a)P(b|a)P(c|(a and b)), but I can't figure out a way to write this without needing P(P), which is not given.

Can anyone work this example out or give me a general nudge in the right direction?

EDIT

I want to thank Lulu for having the right idea. I showed my work to my teacher, who agreed that there was no way to find the probability of P(C and T and (Pop)) without knowing the probability of being part of the subset. He then explained that he just wanted the approach that Lulu proposed, which was you look at the proportion of false negatives that would appear in this population with a P(C) = 0.40. The answer he said was that there will be $60*\frac{65}{935} = 4.17$ false positives and $40*\frac{30}{40} = 30$ true positives in a population of 10, so the answer is $\frac{30}{4.17+30} = 0.8779$, giving our patient an 88% chance of having cancer.

Comment: Are you sure of your numbers?  In your sample space you had $4\%$ of the population having cancer, now you want to take a sample with $40\%$?  Surely, then, any data derived from your sample will be meaningless.

Comment: If you want to, you can assume that the same percent of false negatives and false positive work in your new sample (though you really need to say this).  If so, then you have enough information to solve the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure I made my objection clear.  The fact that your second population is so far off from the first means (or at least strongly suggests) that the second group is subject to some exogenous factor not present in the first (they live next to a radiation site, they are all $90+$ years old, something like that).  A priori I think we need to worry that whatever this exogenous factor is, it might well be correlated to the efficacy of the test you are studying. Certainly, I think it would be foolish to just assume otherwise.

Comment: Also, I strongly advise against using $P$ as a label for events, just to avoid confusion with that other $P$.